# kafka message distribution between consumers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have very simple kafka use case where I am facing issue with message distribution among 2 partitions.

I have 2 partitions on topic and I have 2 consumers for each. I can see more messages went to specific partition and only one consumer is getting messages to process and other one which is subscribed to partition having less messages is sitting idle forever. both consumers are having same group id. I am not able to achieve horizontal scaling with this issue.

Below are key configs I am putting.

```
kafka.session.timeout.ms=10000
kafka.auto.commit=false
kafka.maxpoll.interval.ms=50000
kafka.request.timeout.ms=15000
kafka.maxpoll.records=100
```

**PS:**names are from my prop file and not exactly matching with real kafka property names. 
I need large max poll interval so as to process big chunk in one go. Any guess as what I need to add in config or change it?

Comment: Are you using a key for your messages? If yes, how are those keys distributed? Kafka uses hash of the key to achieve distribution. If keys are not random or not fairly distributed, the consumer load will be skewed as well

Comment: My keys are simple sequence numbers of messages in string format. This is doing fair partitioning for consumers. Issue is that I added second partition recently and it doesn't have so many messages on that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer kafka uses hash of key to decide the partition. It could be that your key are not evenly distributed .In such cases you can define your own  strategy to select partition by producer while producing records.
Create a custom partitoner class and implement partition method of it as following.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.record.InvalidRecordException;

public class CustomPartitioner implements Partitioner {

    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
        int numPartitions = partitions.size();
        if ((keyBytes == null) || (!(key instanceof String)))
            throw new InvalidRecordException("We expect all messages to have a key");
        // Your logic to decide partition based on key
        return 0;// Here return thr partition decided based on key
    }

    public void close() {
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

On producer configuration add following

```
properties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomPartitioner.class.getCanonicalName());
property
```

Comment: Thank you for information.  I don't have control over partition selection  at producer end.  Is there any settings which will trigger rebalance?  In case of Max poll interval expiry,  message is getting redelivered on other consumer but that I don't want to avoid duplicate.

Comment: Property enable.auto.commit is used to store the offset commit for a partition ,whenever rebalance occurs consumer starts reading from offset commit.

Answer (score 0):

**Kafka Producer :** producers send records to a partition based on the record’s key. The default partitioner for Java uses a hash of the record’s key to choose the partition or uses a round-robin strategy if the record has no key. So to be more scalable always use unique key for message

> Producers publish data to the topics of their choice. The producer is responsible for choosing which record to assign to which partition within the topic. **This can be done in a round-robin fashion simply to balance load or it can be done according to some semantic partition function (say based on some key in the record). More on the use of partitioning in a second!**

**If records have same key then they will end in same partition**

You can also send record to particular partition

```
public ProducerRecord(String topic,
          Integer partition,
          K key,
          V value)
```

> Creates a record to be sent to a specified topic and partition

Comment: User can change default partitioner (according to his needs) by overwriting producer `partitioner.class` property.

Comment: Yes, agree. its all controlled by producer only. I came to know about an issue at producer side that they are producing messages with the same key which in turn are popping up on the same partition on broker.